# How to use ground overlay google map android for polygon area to fit the map image in it?

Tags: google-maps-api, android, overlay

I have a park area that is not rectangle or a simple shape. It is just like polygon area. I could load sample image on it for testing, in my android app. 
There it is :

[image]

```
mGroundOverlayRotated = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(
    GroundOverlayOptions()
        .image(mImages[0])
        .position(LatLng_NEAR_NEWARK, 255f, 84f)
        .bearing(110f)
```

It is worked for simple shape like rectangle.

1. `LatLng_NEAR_NEWARK` is latitude/longitude of center of park.
2. `255f` is width of area in meter.
3. `84f` is height of area.

I cannot using width/height for the area like this.
I can't figure out how to use `Position` function in my code to fit it.

[image]

I need something like this :

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250481/show-only-ground-overlays-map-android

I saw something about KML format. I'm not sure about it. Should I use SVG/PNG format for this area instead of JPG?

What approach do I use?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/3tzzwmsx/4/ for rotation of an image

Comment: @Mapperz thank you but it is not useful for that things I want. in android app I must use google map sdk and this site is useful for web api.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they used the tile provider API instead of the ground overlay. https://developer.here.com/apiexplorer-v2-sample-data/template-web-default/examples/custom-tile-overlay/index.html

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay

Or just make the image opaque, so in reality it is a squared GroundOverlay, but through the opacity it seems like the image has the specific form you want.